# Generate graphene input types dynamically

Tags: python, django, validation, graphql, graphene-python

I am sure whether this can be achieved or not. It would be very great if someone suggests any alternative to this or any other supporting packages to achieve this.

Below is my code.

```
class DynamicTypeInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    object_type = graphene.String()
    object_value = graphene.String(required=False) # Can we make this required=True if object_type == "requesting_value"

class WidgetInput(graphene.InputObjectType):
    title = graphene.String()
    dynamic_object_type = graphene.Argument(DynamicTypeInput, required=True)
```

I tried using [graphene-pydantic](https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene-pydantic) for generating graphene models but no use. Its throwing generalized error like `TypeError: Input fields cannot be resolved. The input field type must be a GraphQL input type.` 
Is there any way to achieve this with `graphene` itself?

As of now, I am validating the request once I received it from the user at the service side and am always open to suggestions.

Comment: Do you mean generate graphene input types?

Comment: Yeah. The `object_value`  field is required for some types and optional for some types. I am just trying to make that dynamically based on conditions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using multi InputObjectType

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried multi InputObjectType but no use. As of now, I am validating the request once I received it from the user.